# ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running? Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been working with Docker for about two months now, working on Windows/WSL. The other day I needed to restart my machine and once it restarted I tried setting up my docker containers again and ran into an issue that I have had before, however. All the solutions I used last time do not work, and none on google work either.

I have tried a lot of things, every single possibility on the internet I could fine and I have been stuck on this for at least 8 hours already and wish to waste no more time on it. I will list a few I have already tried but do not work:

1. `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
2. `sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker.exe /usr/bin/docker`
3. using sudo
4. restarted docker
5. reinstalled docker desktop (windows)

The command within our make file runs this:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

We use a MakeFile to make our lives a lot easier in terms of docker commands so usually I would run this command and it should just bring the container up and work fine. But instead I get this:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'up' failed
make: *** [up] Error 1
```

I was then recommended trying `sudo dockerd` which I then get this error, which does half explain the issue but I could not find a clear answer on how to fix my issue:

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

I am really hoping someone is able to help me with this as I am so stuck and need to get this to work.

Comment: Hi Toby, welcome to SO. Are you running the Docker daemon __inside__ of WSL or are you running the Docker for Windows app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out the issue was to do with the groups. The solution that I found worked was to remove the user group "docker" using:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

Then I ran the command for my make file and it worked!

I hope this benefits some of you!

Comment: be sure to logout off your user to allow the commands to be enable, login back and it will works

Comment: I got similar error using 'docker-compose build'. running the command as sudo did the trick. Of course the solution is temporary, but it highlights that the issue with groups.

Answer (score 16):

From [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181#issuecomment-263501259):

> Try running `dockerd` or `sudo dockerd` if required first to start daemon. **If you start `dockerd` with `sudo`** you may want to **run `docker-compose up` with `sudo` also**. otherwise it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to fix this by upgrading to WSL 2 from version 1.

To get your current version in powershell :

```
wsl -l -v
```

For me it was written version 1.

To upgrade from 1 to 2 :

```
wsl --set-version <NAME-FROM-PREVIOUS-COMMAND> 2
```

For me it was Ubuntu :

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

And then the docker daemon could be started as expected inside wsl. (with sudo in my case)

```
sudo dockerd
sudo docker-compose up
```

I hope it could help.